# Compile-time assert that all strings in an array correspond to properties of an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to do a compile-time assert that all the strings in an array correspond to names of properties of the object? For example let's say I have the following:

```
#define PROPERTY_NAMES @[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"age", @"city"]

@interface AARandomClass : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *city;
@property NSString *goofBall;

@property NSNumber *age;

@end
```

I want this not to compile (fail some kind of assertion) because `@"lastName"` IS in `PROPERTY_NAMES` but is not a property of `AARandomClass`. Is there a way to do this?

Also I would separately like compilation to fail because there is a property, `goodBall`, that is a property but that is not in `PROPERTY_NAMES`. IS there a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot do this at compile time, only runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible without writing a script that would get executed at compile time, this is as close as you can get.

You can use `NSStringFromSelector`, if the supplied selector doesn't exist, it will cause a warning time error. It will not check it belongs to a certain class.

```
#define PROPERTY_NAMES @[NSStringFromSelector(@selector(firstName)), ...]
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably test the suggestion before marking it as correct.  It does not work.

Comment: @Avi I should have clarified that it doesn't check if the method is part of the class or that the array is exhaustive (because that's not possible unless you wrote a script to check that), but it does work since it creates an array of methods that exist and will let you know at compile time if you made a mistake and typed a method that doesn't exist. I edited my answer to reflect that this is the closest you can get to what he wants.

Comment: It doesn't work as the selector just has to exist somewhere, not in a specific class.

Comment: @trojanfoe that is pretty much exactly what I wrote ("it doesn't check if the method is part of the class"). Like I said, this is an as-close-as-you-can-get answer because what OP asked is not possible.

Comment: Did you actually try it at all?  I did.  I didn't even get a warning.

Comment: @Avi I didn't try it before because I knew it'd work, and it does. http://oili.me/1cHAk

Comment: Caveat: you have to enable the specific warning when doing command-line builds.  I guess Xcode defaults to that specific warning being enabled.

Comment: @Avi please remove your down vote from my answer. Even if you don't think it deserves an up vote, by now you should at least agree it doesn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: Well, when I down voted, your answer was quite different.  That's the issue with votes... they reflect what the voter thought about the answer at the time they clicked.